# Error: Could not find or load main class ?jar

Tags: java, command-line, jar

Something strange happens when I try running a `java -jar` command programatically on Windows.

When running the command like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); //cmd string is ok
p.waitFor();
```

I get the error

> Error: Could not find or load main class �jar

The `cmd` var is constructed like this:

```
cmd = String.format("java –jar %s –o win -i %s -n %s -d %s -s %s", jarLocation, param1, param2, tgtFilePath, srcFilePath);
```

I tried debugging this issue so I copy pasted the command to CMD and got the same error. However, when I typed it manually and not copy pasted, everything just worked fine.

When getting the bytes of each String I got:

bytes of generated string:

> [106, 97, 118, 97, 32, -30, -128, -109, 106, 97, 114, 32, 110, 112, 116, 95, 108, 105, 99, 101, 110, 115, 101, 46, 106, 97, 114, 32, -30, -128, -109, 111, 32, 119, 105, 110, 32, 45, 105, 32, 104, 111, 115, 116, 105, 100, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 32, 45, 110, 32, 104, 111, 115, 116, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 45, 100, 32, 108, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101, 70, 105, 108, 101, 45, 105, 110, 112, 117, 116, 76, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101, 45, 114, 101, 115, 117, 108, 116, 46, 100, 97, 116, 32, 45, 115, 32, 108, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101, 70, 105, 108, 101, 45, 105, 110, 112, 117, 116, 76, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101]

bytes of hard coded string:

> [106, 97, 118, 97, 32, 45, 106, 97, 114, 32, 110, 112, 116, 95, 108, 105, 99, 101, 110, 115, 101, 46, 106, 97, 114, 32, 45, 111, 32, 119, 105, 110, 32, 45, 105, 32, 104, 111, 115, 116, 105, 100, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 32, 45, 110, 32, 104, 111, 115, 116, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 45, 100, 32, 108, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101, 70, 105, 108, 101, 45, 105, 110, 112, 117, 116, 76, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101, 45, 114, 101, 115, 117, 108, 116, 46, 100, 97, 116, 32, 45, 115, 32, 108, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101, 70, 105, 108, 101, 45, 105, 110, 112, 117, 116, 76, 105, 99, 101, 110, 99, 101]

The jarLocation is the one parameter that is already hard coded and not received as a web service parameter.

What can cause an issue like that?

Comment: how is your manifest file?

Comment: `when I typed it manually and not copy pasted, everything just worked fine` means?

Comment: What I'm running that is causing this issue is a Spring web service. So do you mean the pom.xml? What is supposed to be there?

Comment: @NamanGala it means just that. I tried typing the command like I'm typing these words right now and that made it work.

Comment: Can you retype the command in your code and execute it.

Comment: @NamanGala It's the same thing. If i copy paste the generated string of the command, it returns that error. If I type the command manually in the code, it works

Comment: @YonatanNir do you copy from cmd??

Comment: The string is generated using String.Format since there are some parameters. I copy pasted the generated string inside the cmd variable while I was debugging.

Comment: The `�`is the unicode [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character) used among others for invalid codepoints. I guess the result of your `String.format` execution is wrong. Make an output of the bytes and do the same for the manually entered command and compare where's the difference.

Comment: @SubOptimal OK so let's assume there's a difference. Then what?

Comment: By the way I suspect it's related to the received parameters encoding but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: @YonatanNir `Then what?` Maybe fix it? ... As you don't show what you are doing exactly to generate the `cmd` string. How should we made a proposal to fix it? I believe nobody what's to start a guessing thread here. Provide a simplified example which shows **reproducable** your problem. I'm really sure you will get a quite soon a solution from someone here.

Comment: @SubOptimal if I had known how to fix it, I wouldn't be posting this question. I have added how I create the cmd string. The problem is reproduced as it happens at every call to the web service.

Comment: @YonatanNir Your webservice create the `jarLocation`? How do you retrieve the values from the webservice? Which charset do you use to create/retreive the values. As it's clearly a charset convertion problem you could have already started to investigate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to make it more clear what I proposed you should do.

Amend you code like this

```
// this will be the command which produces �jar
cmd = String.format("java –jar %s –o win -i %s -n %s -d %s -s %s", jarLocation,
          param1, param2, tgtFilePath, srcFilePath);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cmd.getBytes(charsetLatin1)));

// this will be the working command, as you wrote
cmd = "here you type the same command";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cmd.getBytes(charsetLatin1)));
```

Then you compare the bytes and have at least the difference. Based on this you can investigate further.

**update**
Find a short example code for visualising few different dashes, which look quite similar on some fonts.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Dashes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash
        byte[] enDash = {-30, -128, -109};
        byte[] minusSign = {45};
        byte[] emDash = {-30, -128, -108};

        byte[][] charBytes = new byte[3][];
        charBytes[0] = enDash;
        charBytes[1] = minusSign;
        charBytes[2] = emDash;

        for (byte[] bytes : charBytes) {
            String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            char c = s.charAt(0);
            System.out.printf("%d  %s  %s%n", s.length(), c, Character.getName(c));
        }
    }
}
```

You need to check the code which generates the value for `jarLocation`. As the option `-jar` and `-o` contain a `EN DASH` instead of the `HYPHEN-MINUS`.

**the pattern from your code, via copy'n'paste**

```
byte[] b = "java –jar %s –o win -i %s -n %s -d %s -s %s".getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

**output**

[106, 97, 118, 97, 32, `-30, -128, -109`, 106, 97, 114, 32, 37, 115, 32, `-30, -128, -109`, 111, 32, 119, 105, 110, 32, 45, 105, 32, 37, 115, 32, 45, 110, 32, 37, 115, 32, 45, 100, 32, 37, 115, 32, 45, 115, 32, 37, 115]

Which shows the dash before `jar` and `o` is not a `HYPHEN-MINUS`

**solution**

Remove the `–` (EN DASH) in front of the `jar` and `o` option and type it again (as `HYPHEN-MINUS`).

Comment: OK So I did what you said to test and there is a difference in the bytes even though when copy pasting them next to each other I get the same string. And like I said back then.. what now? So I know there's a difference but I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: @YonatanNir As you don't even post the different bytes what do you think we could propose? Did you already investigate how your webservice creates the `jarLocation` value?

Comment: sorry about the missing info. I edited the question itself with the info you asked to see. The difference begins at the 6th byte meaning the '-' of the '-jar'? not sure if that's indeed the case and what can be done about it.

Comment: @YonatanNir Have a look at the small example and comment I add into my answer.

Comment: The problem was indeed because the generated String had an en-dash instead of an hyphen. But why would it happen? When coding the string in the String.Format and when typing the command manually, I pressed the exact same keys.. Why would the String.Format generate it as an en-dash?

Comment: @YonatanNir I don't believe it's a problem of `String.format`. As the problem only occur of the options `-jar` and `-o` but not for the other options `-i`, `-n`, `-d`, `-s`. How does your `String.fomat` pattern looks?

Comment: The pattern is exactly as I posted in the question. It's copy pasted from my code.

Comment: OK I still just not sure why it would write an en-dash when I simply pressed the '-' key but never mind.. Thank you for your help!